# Where should I put my songs in sm-ssc under linux/ubuntu?

Tags: stepmania

I have installed Stepmania fork sm-ssc on Ubuntu 10.10, but I can not make it load my songs. I've downloaded some packages and put it into ~/.sm-ssc/songs/ but they are not loaded.

Where should I place the songs to get them loaded in the game?

Answer (score 1):

Well I found this on the Ubuntu forums but I haven't tested it so I don't know if it will work right or not.

> If you have song packages(smzip), then you have to put them into
>   ~\stepmania\packages\songpackname\file.smzipand
>
> if they are extracted files then they
>   go to:
>
> songs\mixname\songname\

Comment: so I tried this now, but still its not working...

Comment: Going to have to get a Ubuntu expert then sorry it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too old to be relevant but I just installed StepMania on ubuntu 14.04 and it took me a while to find where to put my songs - `/usr/share/games/sm-ssc` has the normal StepMania folder that I'm used to from OSX.

So from there, you drop your pack in like normal: `/usr/share/games/sm-ssc/Songs/Packname`

I installed with apt-get, if that's relevant.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score -2):

try

> ~/.ultrastar/songs works for me

edit: Oh, sorry. That is for performous, you can try that too.